# Использование и размещение layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: мне необходимо создать ДВА layout в activity.

Один создан: linear layout с использованием weight (размещал кнопки). Далее собирался разместить на экране другие элементы, но масса проблем из-за weight.

Подскажите, как разместить второй layout, чтобы он лежал поверх первого? 
Либо как так разместить элементы в первом?

Comment: Вы бы нарисовали, что хотите получить. По вашему описанию ничего полезного посоветовать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Может корневым сделать FrameLayout, в него положить ваш LinearLayout, а рядом второй.

```
<FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout/>
    <LinearLayout/>  
</FrameLayout>
```

Если я вас правильно понял.